# PHP imap functions not working in a shell, but working in controller/browser. (CakePHP 2.x)

Tags: php, cakephp, imap

Preliminary info:

1. CakePHP 2.x
2. Ubuntu using XAMPP on localhost

As part of a web app, I have made a script that checks an email inbox for new messages.  When there are new messages, the script writes the body of the email to a database.  All of this code is located in a controller.  I got the script working great, no problems at all!

I decided I instead want to use this exact same code in a **shell** so I can set up a cron job to do this task instead of having to access the page through the web browser.  After porting the code over to a shell script, when I run the shell I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imap_open()in /path/to/file.php on line 25.
```

And of course the obvious question is "are the imap functions loaded in your php configuration?"  Yes they are.  **I am confused why I have no problem using imap functions when accessing the controller code via the browser, but I get an error when using a shell.**

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your command line php is not built with imap support or the module is not enabled for the cli php, see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=977596. So check that or compile cli with imap support or get a package with imap support built in.

Comment: Or perhaps php-cli's `php.ini` just doesn't have the imap extension enabled.

Comment: @burzum  Thanks a lot, looks like that is it.  Didn't realize that they were using different php.ini's.   In the link you posted, the OP said to fix his problem he just added the line 'extension=imap.so' to the file /etc/php5/cli/php.ini.  I did that but it did not fix the problem.  I'm thinking that I am probably missing the imap.so file and need to download it from somewhere and place it in the proper directory.  Sound right?

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue from where to get it, I kicked every linux installation because of issues like that and differences between every version and distribution... Even if you get just the so file its unlikely it will work with your distribution and version. Try asking in the ubuntu forums for help.